# Tagging for Final Fantasy 14: A Realm Reborn

Tags: discussion, tags

There is currently a tag for Final Fantasy 14 (which I'll refer to as 1.0).  That game has since been shut down and superceded by Final Fantasy XIV: A Realm Reborn (referred to as ARR), which is essentially a remake of the original.

Many several questions originally asked for 1.0 have been provided with answers for ARR.  This makes sense in some ways, but in others it should be considered as a different game because the answers in many cases will be different in ARR than they were in 1.0.

Should the tag be renamed (since 1.0 is no longer available for play) or should a new tag be created?  What of questions that were asked for 1.0 and answered for ARR.

Comment: Since FF14 is no longer playable in its original state, can't we just keep the original tag?

Answer (score 8):

I think we should treat FFXIV: ARR the same way we treat any game that that changes over time, like Minecraft for instance.

- If an **answer** is incorrect, leave a comment asking the poster if they can update it. (Or better yet, just do it yourself!)
- If a **question** is no longer valid (i.e. it asks about features or places that no longer exist), it should be closed. ([Example](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24696/does-hitting-a-sheep-in-the-face-yield-more-wool))

We only have ten [final-fantasy-14](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy-14) questions, so it won't take long for anyone familiar with the game to take a quick look through them for major problems.

Since questions about 1.x aren't useful to anyone anymore, so there's no sense keeping them around and creating a whole new tag for ARR. They would likely only cause confusion.

Comment: A tag synonym though, that might be called for.

Comment: A tag synonym could definitely be useful. I was originally searching for "realm" in the tags tab and was surprised to not find it there.